# Simple REGEX square bracket negative matching or beginning of string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, regex-negation

I have a presumably simple but irritating regex problem, using PHP's preg_match function

Basically, I want to match any digit that does not start with a + and still matches at the beginning of a string.

The current regex I have right now is working but not matching at the beginning of a string.

The regex is

```
/[^\+][?\s]((\d+)?([.,])?\d+)/
```

Here's some test input and expected values it should catch.

---

```
test 10 test
```

catches 10 - correct.

---

```
10 test test
```

Does not catch 10, but it should - incorrect.

---

```
+10 test test
```

Does not catch 10, because it starts with a plus - correct.

---

```
test + 10 test test
```

Does not catch 10, because it starts with a plus and has an optional space between the plus and number - correct

---

test +10 13 51 23

Catches 13, because it is the first number not preceded by the + - correct

---

So the simple question is, how do I make the negative operator in the square brackets not match + symbols, but still work if a number is at the very beginning of a string?

Comment: To match the begining of the line, add `^`. That would give you something like `/^[^\+][?\s]((\d+)?([.,])?\d+)/`. EDIT: That's not answering the whole post. I prepare a full answer.

Comment: So, same question as yesterday, what must be the results with the string `10.20.30`: `10.20` and `30` or nothing at all?

Comment: The first match it catches in the string is the correct one

Comment: In `"+10"`, the `0` doesn't start with a `+` :)

Comment: Why `?` in `[?\s]`? Anyway, more sample input and output please. 3 examples are not where near enough.

Comment: Please add clarifications for edge cases: `10.20.30`, `+5.12`, `+10.20.30`. what must be the results for these cases?

Comment: See Niols answer below, it is the closest full solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you must replace the *a string but not a `+`* part of your regexp by *a string but not a `+` or the begining of the line* :

```
/(?:^|[^\+][?\s])((\d+)?([.,])?\d+)/
```

`(?:` for the unmatching parenthesis, and simply the begining `^` or your pre-match `[^\+][?\s]`.

Edit:

Like Braydon Batungbacal said, this is not exactly what you want, since this regexp fails for `10 test`. I suppose we could do it that way:

```
/(^|[^\+])(^|[?\s])((\d+)?([.,])?\d+)/
```

This is working, but I don't find it really satisfying. If someone finds a better solution...

By the way, note that this regexp also matches when there's no space **after** the number. I don't know if this is what you want or not.

Comment: This solution is very, very close to correct. The only (almost redundant) issue is that if a string begins with a space, and then number " 10 test", it will not match 10.

Comment: Indeed, you're right. What would be a solution ? Maybe we should replace the `[^\+][?\s]` by *not a number* ?

Comment: We could do it twice : `(^|[^\+])(^|[?\s])`. This is working, but not really satisfying.